ansible.builtin.ini, Invalid filename: 'None
I am trying to parse ini file by ansible.builtin.ini, but I got the error message:

"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'ansible.builtin.ini'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleParserError'>, original message: Invalid filename: 'None'"


My playbook as this:
- name: Parse dependency jars
  set_fact:
    common_jars: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.ini', 'common-dependency', section='common', file='DEPENDENCY-JARS.ini') }}"
    interface_jars: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.ini', 'interface-dependency', section='interface', file='DEPENDENCY-JARS.ini') }}"

DEPENDENCY-JARS.ini file is placed at the same path with playbook file, does anyone know why it always throw above errors? Ansible version is 2.9, thanks.

Q: The file is on the same path as the playbook file.
A: Use the special variable playbook_dir. For example, given the file for testing
shell> cat DEPENDENCY-JARS.ini 
[common]
common-dependency = foo

[interface]
interface-dependency = bar

the play
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    filename: "{{ playbook_dir }}/DEPENDENCY-JARS.ini"

  tasks:

    - name: Parse dependency jars
      set_fact:
        common_jars: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.ini',
                                'common-dependency',
                                section='common',
                                file=filename) }}"
        interf_jars: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.ini',
                                'interface-dependency',
                                section='interface',
                                file=filename) }}"

    - debug:
        msg: |
          common_jars: {{ common_jars }}
          interf_jars: {{ interf_jars }}

gives (abridged)
  msg: |-
    common_jars: foo
    interf_jars: bar

